# Jasmine angular testing factory method success error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test a angular controller mocking the calls made to a service using jasmine. I want to check if is success or error. I tried to do this with $q but it doesn't affect to my return. How to do this?
I tried like this:

```
$scope.savestuff = function () {
                 return some.method.test($scope.data, {
                success: function () {
                    return true;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    $scope.error= error.data.message;
                }
       });
        }
```

[MyCode][1]

service:

```
.service('some', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

     service.method = {
        test: function (data, config) {
             return service.run({
                call: $http({
                    method: "POST",
                }),
                success: config.success,
                error: config.error
            });
        }
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: you want to test your success and error functions?

Comment: Yes i want to test success function

Comment: i don't see the `action.user.update` method and it's behaviour

Comment: I added service code.

Comment: and what is that service.run?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JLNAuY8U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. mock `service.run,`

```
spyOn(service, 'run').and.callFake(function(obj){
    return obj.success(); 
    //or obj.error({data: {message: 'Server error'}});
});
```

## 2. mock `$http` with `$httpBackend`

```
$httpBackend.expect('POST','/user/edit').respond({
    response: {something: here}
});
```

## 3. would be to mock action.user

```
spyOn(action.user, 'update')...
```

Comment: You haven't bothered to check the code OP already have, have you?

Comment: @maurycy I did. And I still think my answer is the solution.

Comment: If you did you would know he already mocks the `update` service

Comment: no, he mocks it but without providing function for the mocked function... that's why I was providing here the correct one... please revert back your negative vote. Thanks.

Comment: When i trying to spyOn i got _ "update has already been spied upon"_